# C++ and Python 3 memory leak using PyArg_ParseTuple

Tags: python, c++

I'm not a C++ developer so i don't really know what I'm doing. Unfortunately I have to debug the following code but I'm not making any progress.

```
static PyObject* native_deserialize(PyObject *self, PyObject *args){
  PyObject * pycontent;
  int len;
  PyObject * props  = NULL;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "|SiO", &pycontent, &len, &props);

  RecordParser reader("onet_ser_v0");
  TrackerListener* listener;

  listener = new TrackerListener(props);
  #if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
      reader.parse((unsigned char*)PyBytes_AsString(pycontent), len, *listener);
  #else
      reader.parse((unsigned char*)PyString_AsString(pycontent), len, *listener);
  #endif
  return listener->obj;
}
```

Here is the python that calls that code:

```
    clsname, data = pyorient_native.deserialize(content,
                                content.__sizeof__(), self.props)
```

This code creates a nasty memory leak. In fact, when I run this code, it kills my memory within 20 minutes.

I looked at the code but can't find the problem in the C++.

How can I prevent rogue C++ code from killing my Python code? Is there a way to flag C++ code from within python to be recycled regardless whether the C++ created a memory leak?

Is there a way I can force the memory to be garbage collected in C++. How can I find the exact leak in C++ by running python?

My biggest issue is understanding Py_XDECREF and Py_XINCREF and the rest of the reference counting macros. I'm reading the docs but obviously I'm missing some context because I can't figure out where and when to use these. I have loads of respect for C++ developers. Their jobs seem unnecessarily difficult :(

Comment: `native_deserialize()` is badly designed. At least you need to pass `listener` out of the function and delete it after using `listener->obj`. If you can change return value of PyObject pointer to a PyObject object, that will be much better.

Comment: I agree with you. I tried changing the code in order to do what you mentioned but as soon as I delete the listener, the code breaks. I've tried cloning the obj and returning the clone instead but have been unsuccessful at that. I'm a noob at C++ :(

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was to Py_XDECREF the reference count for al the created objects. I still don't know exactly how, why and were as many of this still doesn't make sense to me.

I found this page that points out some of the pitfalls of these macros.

https://wingware.com/psupport/python-manual/2.3/ext/node22.html

There is the documentation but that wasn't very helpful.

https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/refcounting.html

Maybe someone can share something else that is easier to consume for us non C++ peoplez?

Comment: you should update the question if you want to ask more questions, instead of answering

Comment: Can you post your solution. The links are not working.